# Port exhaustion with log4net RemotingAppender

Tags: c#, .net, windows, log4net

I have an enterprise server application under stress test with many clients connecting, requesting some responses and disconnecting when done. After a while (could be days or hours) they fail to connect with error:

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

We use log4net and after increasing the log4net level to "Trace" the error started happening much sooner which pointed to the guilty party :)

Turns out we have a port exhaustion because of the RemotingAppender we use and no service active to receive the logs. Figured that one out by looking at the "Network Activity" for the server in the "Resource Monitor" (many inactive localhost:7070 connections).

Here is a little test program to reproduce the issue (may need to run for a while depending on PC):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        bool exit = false;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            exit = true;
        });

        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (Program));

        long count = 0;
        while (!exit)
        {
            log.Info($"Loop counter = {count++}.");
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    log.Info("Connecting to server...");
                    client.Connect("google.com", 80);
                    log.Info("Connected to server.");
                    log.Debug($"End points: {client.Client.LocalEndPoint} => {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) log.Debug("Dummy log line.");
                    client.Close();
                    log.Info("Disconnected from the server.");
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    log.Warn("Woke up after 10ms.");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.Error(e);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    exit = true;
                }
            }
            log.Error("Fake error.");
            log.Warn("Press any key to stop the test :)");
        }
    }
```

And example log4net configuration is here:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level: %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RemotingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender" >
      <sink value="tcp://localhost:7070/LoggingSink" />
      <lossy value="false" />
      <bufferSize value="0" />
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="Console" />
      <appender-ref ref="RemotingAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Work-around at the moment is to comment out RemotingAppender from the "root" section in the configuration. I wonder is there a better way to configure RemotingAppender in order to avoid this (will try to play with bufferSize value)?

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid port exhaustion is use/increase the buffer size value in the log4net configuration for the "RemoteAppender". Something like this:

```
 <appender name="RemotingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender" >
  <sink value="tcp://localhost:7070/LoggingSink" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <bufferSize value="100" />
</appender>
```

The large the value the more log messages will get into a buffer before being sent (and new socket connection used). Note that if you are running listener like Log2Console on a port 7070 there are no issues as the same TCP connection is reused.
The only downside of increasing the buffer value is that you may not get every log message instantly (as it is published), so be aware of this if you are correlating multiple log sources or your application suddenly crashes.